# Matlab .exe not working

Tags: image, webcam, matlab, matlab-deployment

I have a Matlab code, which i've made into an exe and run from VB6. I need to continuously keep saving an image acquired from a webcam in the code, which does not seem to be happening. When i run the exe, the picture is not saved at that location, instead it gets saved only after i close it. But i need the image to get saved during the running of the exe file. My code is :

```
function [im]=cam_img()
clear all
clc
tic;

vid=videoinput('winvideo');
vid.FramesPerTrigger=1;
while(1)
endtime=toc;
if(mod(round(endtime),3)==0)
    image=getsnapshot(vid);
    image=rgb2gray(image);
    imwrite(image,'pixellinkimage.jpg')
end
end
end
```

How can i go about this? please let me know. thanks a lot!

Comment: What happens when you run this code from Matlab?  Is the image regularly saved?

Comment: @grantnz yes, it is. the image is refreshed and saved regularly.

Comment: @user877852: busy looping is a bad idea, use a [TIMER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/timer.html) object instead

Comment: @user877852: also instead of the use of tic/toc, why not use a simple `pause(3)`?

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is this:

```
while(1)
```

this is an infinite loop and will never quit

Comment: hi slayton, thanks! Hmm okay. But i do want to keep getting the snapshot of the video at all times. Is there any way else i could do so? Why is it that the image gets saved only once i close the .exe though?